Как на строне клиента вызвать ajax в drupal10?
Форма, выводится в блоке, у формы есть интерактивные методы.
Задача - интерактивно менять содержимое формы на стороне клиента путём вызова метода из другой формы.
Сейчас я реализовал несколько в обход. Добавил невидимую кнопку с вызовом ajax метода. Нахожу её и вызываю метод click(). Но понимаю, что можно это делать без кнопки и более правильно.
$form['opn_1'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#submit' => ['::goChange'],
            '#id' => 'opn_1',
            '#value' => '5',
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
                'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
                'method' => 'replace',
                'event' => 'click',
                'progress' => array('type' => 'none')
            ],
            '#attributes' => [
              'style' => ['display:none']
            ]
        ];


    public function goChange(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form_state->set('mode', 5);
        $form_state->setRebuild();
    }

А теперь собственно вопрос, есть ли способ на стороне клиента дёрнуть функцию формы и получить событие, что форма была изменена?
